# jQuery animate() not animating left property

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I tried to create a simple image slider using jQuery and I am stuck around with animate property of jQuery. Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adityasingh773/w64p77fs/) for the same. My jQuery code looks like this(Propert width is just for reference to show that code is working, it can be omitted)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
    moveRight();
}, 1000);
});
var imageCount = $("#slider-wrapper .images img").length();
function moveRight(){
$(".images img").animate({
    left: '300px',
    width: '25%'
}, 1000, function(){
    $(".images img").css('left', '');
});
}
```

the animate function is not animating property `left` but the property `width` is animated. What am I doing wrong? Is it something related to my CSS?

Comment: You may need to add `img { position:relative; } ` to your css – but I'm not sure how you want the animation to work.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the problem?  Does the animation work if you take the interval and animation callback out?

Comment: @Djave, `width` is just for reference, I tried to implement only `left` and that is not working

Comment: @Sandy, yes it works that way.

Comment: @LuckyAli have you tried removing **just** the interval, or **just** the callback?

Comment: @Dave, `position:relative` worked just fine. Can you just explain me what happened here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to add `position: relative` or `position: absolute` in your CSS file to the selector `.images img`. The left property works correctly with 'position'.

```
.images img {
  position: relative; /* Or absolute/fixed */
}
```